# When should a method return CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, future, completable-future

What are the general guidelines on when should a method return CompletableFuture? Suppose there are two classes A and B, where class B has a method performTask() which does a lot of IO, and class A invokes the performTask() method
In Java one can write the multi-threaded code using the following approaches :

- Let the caller of the method decide whether to execute a method asynchronously using ThreadPool. In this case, A will call the performTask() method asynchronously so that class B doesn't need to make its methods asynchronous.
- Let the method performTask() return a Future or CompletableFuture so that class A simply calls performTask().

What are the general guidelines on which approach is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer**

You decide.

**The little bit longer answer**

It depends:

- When you know that callers will more often than not want to wait for `performTask()` to finish, make the method synchronous.
- When you know that callers will more often than not want to continue doing stuff immediately after calling `performTask()`, and either not care about the result, or check it later, make the method asynchronous.
- When you don't know, see the short answer.